# How to find particular element from duplicate using css selector

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
<span class="benefit_subtitle"> - What applications are utilizing my network?</span>
```

This is same path is giving more than 6 matchings.. I need to select the one element from the path using only css selector

css : `span.benefit_subtitle`

I want to covert this xpath into css

```
By.xpath('(//span[@class="benefit_subtitle"])[3]')
```

Comment: can you provide the html of all 6 matching nodes and your desired output using cssSelector ?

Comment: @cruisepandey - all the elemnts are same html..

Comment: @cruisepandey - <span class="benefit_subtitle"><some text></span>

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(span[class=benefit_subtitle]:nth-of-type(3)))
```

Sauce labs has a good [page](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) on these.

Comment: Its not working.Can you please provide the different solution

Comment: If you try to find this 'span[class=benefit_subtitle]:nth-of-type(3)' in the inspector does the element get highlighted? Secondly do you have any iFrames in the source?

Comment: if i try above code, its showing no matching nodes.. if i try the below mentioned code, its showing 6 matching nodes.. How to fetch first elemnet among the 6 nodes?? span[class=benefit_subtitle]:nth-of-type(2)..... Yes i have iframe but that's switched..

Comment: If you want the first you can use :first-of-type

Comment: If i want to get 4th element what should i need to give??